# jquery addclass to the clicked radio button span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="tests">
    <input name="premise" id="premise" type="radio" class="required" value="0"><span>0</span>
    <input name="premise" type="radio" class="required" value="1"><span>1</span>  
    <input name="premise" type="radio" class="required" value="2"><span>2</span>
    <input name="premise" type="radio" class="required" value="3"><span>3</span>
    <input name="premise" type="radio" class="required" value="4"><span>4</span>
    <input name="premise" type="radio" class="required" value="5"><span>5</span>      
    </div>
```

here is the jquery I am using that unfortunately doesn't work: `jQuery("#premise").children().addClass('redtext');`

I am trying to add the class redtext to the clicked radio box. so if you click on radio with the value=1, then the number 1 that can be found inside the span will be in red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing the jQuery children() operator.  children() operates on children of an element in the DOM tree, but in this case the span which you're trying to add a class to is a sibling of the `<input>` tag, not a child.  So

```js
$("#premise").next().addClass('redtext');
```

should add the class to the closest sibling after the `<input>` in the DOM tree, which is the `<span>` you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `<span>` is not a child of `<input>` in your code...
you can change `children` with `next` 
This should work:

```
$('#premise').next().addClass('redtext');
```

Comment: Lol **@ThiefMaster**. Important space indeed!